# How to reload to same path when i reload the page again,i am using can active routing in angular 4

Tags: angular, path, routes, guard

Ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    canActivate: [AuthguardGuard],
    component: MyNavComponent
  },
  { 
  path: '**', 
  redirectTo: 'login', 
  pathMatch: 'full' 
  }

];
```

When i am in dashboard path and reloading it i am getting a empty webpage , how to resolve this please help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

Enable initial navigation in your AppModule router configuration. Example below:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [/*your imports */,
              RouterModule.forRoot([/*your routes here*/], { initialNavigation: 'enabled' })],
    exports: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: `initialNavigation: 'enabled'` tells the routing mechanism that on loading the angular app, it should try and navigate to the url in the browser (if it can find it in your routing configurations). Thus enabling you to reload a page in your browser even deep in your routing tree and still get to the same route.